# lotusnotes 8.5 print button for a persivic printer

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to make a second print button in lotus notes 8.5 for a persivic printer that is not the Default printer.
Does anybody knows a script for this.

I started to play with @Command(FilePrint) but that is as far as I got.
I'm a noob with this but I'm here to learn ;)

With kind regards,

Rene

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to use lotusscript, take a look at the [NotesUIDocument.print](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PRINT_METHOD.html) method, in 8.5 it has a parameter allowing you to specify which printer to use.

This example script prints one copy of the current document on the printer "Printer247":

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
  Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
  Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
  Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
  Call uidoc.Print( 1, 0, 0, False, "Printer247" )
End Sub
```

Comment: I have played around with it and I came to this:              @Command([FilePrintSetup]);  @Command([FilePrint]) / when I have this I can select the printer I want and then it goes to that print option. But I would like that the printer is already been selected by the command script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay, I have tryed the Sample script but I get this error: An Operator or semicolon was expected but none was encounterd: 'click'

Comment: Rene, change the type of action from "@Formula" to "LotusScript"

Comment: Again thanks for the headsup, but I can't use LotusScript because At the moment I do not have LotusDominoDesigner installed is there a other way?